# CSS fonts doesn't load in browser after I changed the OS (from windows7 to Ubuntu)

Tags: html, css, fonts

So I changed my windows 7 to ubuntu, downloaded my files from drive and opened it up with VScode. No files are missing, but the fonts are not loading in my browser (tested with both firefox and chrome, it doesnt work). My font css file and stylesheet are both linked to my html and from before.

[here's the look from the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu7oY.png)

[the font files are not missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmJDe.png)

[linked with no errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGuZA.png)

Comment: Extra Info: it's only when I open the file in my browser. I deployed it via netlify and the fonts works fine there